# Rails NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Hyperclient:Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

This is quite a 'newbie' question but I've been searching and can't seem to find anything to solve an error with using [hyperclient](https://github.com/codegram/hyperclient) in a rails app, in one of my Model's methods.

Whenever I run `rails c` I get the error 
`` NoMethodError (undefined method `new' for Hyperclient:Module) ``

In my **gemfile**

```
gem "hyperclient"
```

-- ran `bundle install`

in model **app/models/artwork.rb**

```
class Artwork < ApplicationRecord
    require "hyperclient"

    def self.test_artsy
        api = Hyperclient.new('https://api.artsy.net/api') do |api|
          puts api
        end
    end
end
```

I've looked at the [docs on hyperclient](https://rubydoc.org/github/codegram/hyperclient/master/Hyperclient) and have seen that they do have a method for .new (also on their examples) so I know it's something I've done incorrectly but I'm not sure what else to try?

The code did work when opening irb in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified any version in your `Gemfile` so it might happen that `Bundler` will not install the latest version and that's what I am guessing might happened here.

You can check which version is installed by doing:
`cat Gemfile.lock | grep hyperclient`

You have at least two options here:

1) 
`bundle update hyperclient` - this should update your `Gemfile.lock` to the latest version

2) 
`bundle remove hyperclient
bundle add hyperclient --version "0.9"` - this will update your Gemfile and then run `bundle install` that will regenerate your `Gemfile.lock`

The second option is recommended since it is a good practice to always specify version for the gems you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much! This definitely set me on the right path, it looks like I had to do some additional updates on the gem "Faraday" that Hyperclient also uses — a bit of uninstalling and reinstalling these two gems and updating the Gemfile as `gem "hyperclient", "~> 0.9.1"
 gem "faraday", "~> 0.17.3"` and it's all working now as I wanted!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!